# algorithm to assign points to winning users

Tags: algebra-precalculus, scoring-algorithm

I have a set of users who have won a game

```
('jim', 12), ('james', 54), ('john', 76), ('dave', 22), ('garry', 34), ('stuart', 16)
```

I would to award them a share of points based on there position in the game on a sliding scale. The 'global pot' is $100 and I would like the winner to get the most with other users getting less based on a sliding scale to there position.

Would anyone know of an 'scoring' algorithm to do this...? Similar to ones used in poker but with a fixed pot

Comment: I think you are going to need to be much more specific, here - how exactly do you want the scale to 'slide'?  Really, this is just a matter of sorting the list by score and then applying whatever algorithm you decide to use.

Answer (score 3):

You can give them their share in proportion to their share of the points.  If $t=12+54+76+22+34+16=214$, then jim gets $\$100\cdot \frac {12}{t}=\$5.61$ and so on.